# JQuery animate method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically resize an element using JQuery `.animate` method, but it does not work:

```js
function showAudioDb(){
  var dbInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var dbLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var dbRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var leftCover = Math.round(dbLeft/60*100);
    var rightCover = Math.round(dbRight/60*100);
    $('.audioLeft audioCover').animate({height: leftCover+'%'}, "slow")
    $('.audioRight audioCover').animate({height: rightCover+'%'}, "slow")
  }, 500);
}

showAudioDb();
```

```css
.channels {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
  resize: both;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.str0 {stroke:white;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str1 {stroke:#999999;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.fil1 {fill:none}
.fil0 {fill:#333333}

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 10%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 15%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 35%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
}

.audioRight {
  left: 60%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="width: 476px; height: 266px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">
      <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1" audiopid="[0x33]" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:[0x33],width:0,height:0" interface="192.168.222.15" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="undefined" serviceprovider="provider" videopid="[0x31]" videostream="format:h264,type:video,pid:[0x31],width:1920,height:1080">undefined</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="audioVideo">
      <td colspan="5" class="vid"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="sound">
        <div class="audiodb">
            <div class="audioNumbers">
              <span class="db max"><p>0</p></span>
              <span class="db high"><p>6</p></span>
              <span class="db normal"><p>18</p></span>
              <span class="db low"><p>60</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="levels level0"></span>
            <span class="levels level1"></span>
            <span class="levels level2"></span>
            <span class="levels level3"></span>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfo">
      <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
      <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
      <td class="fps">FPS</td>
      <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
      <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
      <td>Left</td><td>Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfoValues">
      <td class="resolValue">1920x1080</td>
      <td class="aspectValue">---</td>
      <td class="fpsValue">---</td>
      <td class="vformatValue">H-264</td>
      <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
      <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
      <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The grey part in these two green columns are separate `divs` which should cover some part of the column. What am I doing wrong with `.animate` method?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/1hc2b5q5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `.` in front of `audioCover` class in your code. It should like below.

```
$('.audioLeft .audioCover').animate({height: leftCover+'%'}, "slow")
$('.audioRight .audioCover').animate({height: rightCover+'%'}, "slow")
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1hc2b5q5/5/)

**Code Snippet**

```js
function showAudioDb(){
  var dbInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var dbLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var dbRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
    var leftCover = Math.round(dbLeft/60*100);
    var rightCover = Math.round(dbRight/60*100);
    $('.audioLeft .audioCover').animate({height: leftCover+'%'}, "slow")
    $('.audioRight .audioCover').animate({height: rightCover+'%'}, "slow")
  }, 500);
}

showAudioDb();
```

```css
.channels {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
  resize: both;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.str0 {stroke:white;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str1 {stroke:#999999;stroke-width:3.97;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.fil1 {fill:none}
.fil0 {fill:#333333}

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 10%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 15%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 35%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
}

.audioRight {
  left: 60%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="width: 476px; height: 266px; position: relative;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">
      <td colspan="5" class="channelName" id="channel1" audiopid="[0x33]" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:[0x33],width:0,height:0" interface="192.168.222.15" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="undefined" serviceprovider="provider" videopid="[0x31]" videostream="format:h264,type:video,pid:[0x31],width:1920,height:1080">undefined</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="channelNumber">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="audioVideo">
      <td colspan="5" class="vid"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="sound">
        <div class="audiodb">
            <div class="audioNumbers">
              <span class="db max"><p>0</p></span>
              <span class="db high"><p>6</p></span>
              <span class="db normal"><p>18</p></span>
              <span class="db low"><p>60</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioLeft">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="audioBackground audioRight">
              <div class="audioCover"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="levels level0"></span>
            <span class="levels level1"></span>
            <span class="levels level2"></span>
            <span class="levels level3"></span>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfo">
      <td class="resolution">Resolution</td>
      <td class="aspect">Aspect</td>
      <td class="fps">FPS</td>
      <td class="vformat">V-Format</td>
      <td class="aformat">A-Format</td>
      <td>Left</td><td>Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="channelInfoValues">
      <td class="resolValue">1920x1080</td>
      <td class="aspectValue">---</td>
      <td class="fpsValue">---</td>
      <td class="vformatValue">H-264</td>
      <td class="aformatValue">MP2</td>
      <td class="leftBarValue">---</td>
      <td class="rightBarValue">---</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, how could I miss that? Thank you.